# What does the phrase "slice your timeline" mean here?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrases

Does the word "slice" simply mean "cut" in the following sentence?

**The new tool palette includes cursor modes—Hand, Zoom, Blade, and Track Select—that enable you to quickly zoom in, move, and even slice your timeline.**

I am assuming that the word "timeline" is used with all three action words, i.e. zoom in, move and slice. However, I am wondering if one can slice the timeline. Or is the phrase "clips on your timeline" implied here?

The quoted sentence describes a function of the video editing and screencast tool, ScreenFlow.

Comment: The "timeline" on a chart is usually the x-axis (horizontal), with the earliest date/time on the left, and the latest on the right. I imagine "slice your timeline" means drag the cursor from left to right (or right to left) to identify ***part*** of the entire x-axis (not necessarily starting at the left margin, or ending at the right margin), and have the chart redrawn so the selected span now fills the *entire* horizontal  space. Often this is done using a smaller chart underneath the main one.

Answer (score 1):

It probably does mean “cut your timeline” or perhaps “cut a section out of your timeline”. I can't perceive any reference to “clips on your timeline” from the content you have quoted.

Understanding the exact intended meaning here is really more about fully understanding the context (the palette tool being discussed and how it works) rather than understanding the English language.

Comment: Can the quoted sentence be simply rephrased as "Do you want to take a shot of yourself speaking in the screenshot?"